How can I reference the active cell within a loop through different sheets?
I am stuck where it is properly reading that I have two rows that fulfill the "If" condition, but it is copying row 1 both times on separate sheets, rather than row 8 and 10. Is there a way to have it recognize one cell at a time and copy it if it fills the conditions.
I have tried the following code
Sub RunReport()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rptSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Range
    Dim srcSheets As Variant
    
        Set rptSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
        Set srcSheets = Worksheets(Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "SheetD"))
        
        For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
            For Each i In srcSheet.Range("A5:W358")
                If srcSheet.Range(i, "B").Value <> "" And srcSheet.Range(i, "O").Value = "" Then
                    srcSheet.Cells(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination = rptSheet.Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next i
        Next srcSheet
        
End Sub


Copy Matching Rows (2 Criteria)
A Quick Fix
Sub RunReport()
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim srcSheets As Sheets: Set srcSheets = wb.Sheets(Array( _
        "SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "SheetD"))
    
    Dim rptSheet As Worksheet: Set rptSheet = wb.Sheets("Report")
    Dim rptCell As Range: Set rptCell = rptSheet _
        .Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Dim srcSheet As Object, srcRange As Range, srcRow As Range
        
    For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
        If TypeOf srcSheet Is Worksheet Then
            Set srcRange = srcSheet.Range("A5:W358")
            For Each srcRow In srcRange.Rows
                If Len(CStr(srcRow.Columns("B").Value)) > 0 _
                        And Len(CStr(srcRow.Columns("O").Value)) = 0 Then
                    srcRow.Copy Destination:=rptCell
                    Set rptCell = rptCell.Offset(1)
                End If
            Next srcRow
        End If
    Next srcSheet
        
End Sub


Another possible solution.
The variable i refers to the row of the range being copied.
Sub RunReport()
    Dim srcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim rptSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Range
    Dim srcSheets As Variant
    
        Set rptSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
        Set srcSheets = Worksheets(Array("SheetA", "SheetB", "SheetC", "SheetD"))
        
        For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
            For Each i In srcSheet.Range("A5:W358").Rows
                If i.Columns("B").Value <> "" And i.Columns("O").Value = "" Then
                    i.Copy Destination:=rptSheet.Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next i
        Next srcSheet
        
End Sub



i is a range object, Cells(i) and Range(i, "B") are not the right way to reference a range object. eg. assuming i=5, for cell B5, use either Cells(i, "B") , Cells(i, 2) or Range("B" & i).

Destination:= ... For the named argument, use := instead of =.


Microsoft documentation:

Range object (Excel)


Range.Cells property (Excel)

        Dim iR As Long
        For Each srcSheet In srcSheets
            For iR = 5 To 358
                If srcSheet.Cells(iR, "B").Value <> "" And srcSheet.Cells(iR, "O").Value = "" Then
                    srcSheet.Rows(iR).Copy Destination:=rptSheet.Cells(rptSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next 
        Next srcSheet

